# is it possible to trigger `ssh-add <key>` only when I ssh into a box? (from Cygwin)

Tags: ssh, cygwin, ssh-agent

I've got my `.bash_profile` set up to `eval $(ssh-agent)` so I can quickly connect to servers.  If I add `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_my_key` to my `.bash_profile` as well, I'll have to type the ssh key passphrase in every terminal window, even if I didn't intend to use that terminal window for logging into a server.

I could create an alias to make it trivially easy to type the `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_my_key` line (so I don't have to stop my train of thought about what I'm trying to accomplish and think instead about how I named my key) but I still have to remember to do that before I ssh into a box.

I'm used to working in OS X, where all this is handled almost transparently by the Keychain, and I just `ssh` away without having to think about access.  I'd rather not have to change my mental habits, even though I'm now primarily working from a Windows box.  In Windows the ssh-agent dies as soon as I

I'd also rather not do this with aliases or functions for ssh, if it can be avoided.  I think that creating aliases and functions that replace normal commands and programs is a somewhat fragile and risky solution: if *another* problem comes up in the future for which the only solution is to replace `ssh` then my alias or (more likely) function becomes yet more complex and brittle.  Increasingly so the third time, etc. etc.  Nonetheless, this *may* be the only solution.  Furthermore, to be useful, the function would have to somehow first check whether the key had already been added, otherwise I'd be adding it every time I logged in, which would accomplish nothing.

Does `ssh` have some setting to do this automatically?  Is there some better solution than adding `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_my_key` to my `.bash_profile`?

Comment: "In Windows the ssh-agent dies as soon as I"... What's the rest of the sentence? It seems like the 'right' solution would be to get an ssh agent running on your local machine (windows it seems), and forward the agent through the ssh connections so you only have to add the key once (until you reboot or kill the local ssh-agent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having `ssh-agent` generate a random socket name, use the `-a` option to make it always use the same name. Export this name in the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable. When you log in, run

```
rm -f "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
ssh-agent -a "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
```

This way all your terminals will connect to the same agent. Then, either start one terminal when you log in that runs `ssh-add` and prompts you for your passphrase, or set `SSH_ASKPASS` to `win-ssh-askpass` so that ssh itself will prompt you for a passphrase.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it looks like you forgot the `-a` after ssh-agent in the code provided.

Answer (score 3):

Don't add anything to any of your shell startup scripts, this is unnecessary hackery.

Instead, add

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

to your .ssh/config

Like this, ssh-add is run automatically the first time you ssh into another box. You only have to re-enter your key when it expires from ssh-agent or after you reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, create a wrapper function and put it in your `.bashrc`.

Something like this:

```
ssh () {
  ssh-add -l | grep 'The agent has no identities.' 2>&1 > /dev/null && ssh-add
  /usr/bin/ssh "$@"
}
```

Although since you're using Cygwin, you'll need the proper path to wherever ssh really is.

Comment: Maybe using `/usr/bin/env ssh "$@"` instead of `/usr/bin/ssh "$@"` would be better?